# Geting first 255 chars of ntext field using LINQ to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using LINQ to ENTITIES to pull data from a SQL Server and I am trying to get just the first 255 characters from one of the columns who's data type is `NTEXT`. When I try I get the error:

> Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of len function

The code producing the error is:

```
Subject = (yt.Message.Length > 255) ?  yt.Message.Substring(0, 255) :  yt.Message
```

Is there an easy way to either get the length so I can check it or just get the first 255 characters of an `NTEXT` column?

Trying to do `yt.Message.ToString().Length` gives the same error.

This is a third party DB for a forum software I am using and since I don't know anything about how that system works I want to stay away from altering any of the schema.

Comment: Is there a reason you cant use `ToString`?

Comment: I'm assuming that this is a legacy table, for new tables should use nVarChar(MAX).

Comment: @JonathanAllen It is a  third party DB for the YetAnotherForum.Net forum software.

Comment: Maybe you could try yt.Message.Take(255).ToList()?

Comment: `NTEXT` is a really hard-to-use and a **deprecated** datatype. I would definitely recommend changing this to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` - once you've done that, you can treat it as a normal string column - it's really worth it! (and works without data loss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear there is a way to do this in LINQ but what I ended up doing is creating a normal LINQ query to pull all the data then put a method in the ViewModel that returns the amount of characters I want.

```
public string Subject
    {
        get
        {
            return (yt.Message.Length > 255) ? yt.Message.Substring(0, 255) : yt.Message

        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a view.

```
CREATE VIEW MyView
AS
    SELECT  MyKey,
            LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), MyValue), 255) AS MyValueSummary
    FROM    dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: How would you go about calling this with LINQ from an EF 6 system.

Comment: My general advice is to not use ORMs for professional work. But if you must, EF can read from views just as easily as it can from tables.